# Breaking an iterative function in Python before a condition turns False

Tags: python, boolean, iteration

This is for a school assignment.

I have been tasked to define a function determining the largest square pyramidal number up to a given integer(argument). For some background, these are square pyramidal numbers:

1 = 1^2

5 = 1^2+2^2

14 = 1^2+2^2+3^2

So for a function and parameter `largest_square_pyramidal_num(15)`, the function should return 14, because that's the largest number within the domain of the argument.

I get the idea. And here's my code:

```
def largest_square_pyramidal_num(n):
    sum = 0
    i = 0
    while sum < n:
        sum += i**2
        i += 1
    return sum
```

Logically to me, it seemed nice and rosy until I realised it doesn't stop when it's supposed to. When n = 15, sum = 14, sum < n, so the code adds one more round of i**2, and n is exceeded. I've been cracking my head over how to stop the iteration *before* the condition sum < n turns false, including an attempt at break and continue:

```
def largest_square_pyramidal_num(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n+1):
        sum += i**2
        if sum >= n:
            break
        else:
            continue
    return sum
```

Only to realise it doesn't make any difference.

Can someone give me any advice? Where is my logical lapse? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: why not just return `sum - (i-1)**2` (`while` version) or `sum - i**2` (`for` version)? i.e. you undo the addition that pushed you over the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that `continue` in the second code piece is redundant. This instruction is used for scenario when you don't want the code in `for` loop to continue but rather to start a new iteration (in your case there are not more instructions in the loop body).

For example, let's print every number from 1 to 100, but skip those ending with 0:

```py
for i in range(1, 100 + 1):
    if i % 10 != 0:
        print(i)

for i in range(1, 100 + 1):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        # i don't want to continue executing the body of for loop,
        # get me to the next iteration
        continue
    print(i)
```

The first example is to accept all "good" numbers while the second is rather to exclude the "bad" numbers. IMHO, `continue` is a good way to get rid of some "unnecessary" elements in the container rather than writing an `if` (your code inside `if` becomes extra-indented, which worsens readability for bigger functions).

As for your first piece, let's think about it for a while. You `while` loop terminates when the piramid number is **greater or equal than n**. And that is not what you really want (yes, you may end up with a piramid number which is equal to **n**, but it is not always the case).

What I like to suggest is to generate a pyramid number until in **exceedes n** and then take a step back by removing an extra term:

```py
def largest_square_pyramidal_num(n):
    result = 0
    i = 0
    while result <= n:
        i += 1
        result += i**2
    result -= i ** 2
    return result
```

2 things to note:

1. don't use *sum* as a name for the variable (it might confuse people with built-in `sum()` function)
2. I swapped increment and *result* updating in the loop body (such that *i* is up-to-date when the `while` loop terminates)

So the function reads like this: **keep adding terms until we take too much and go 1 step back**.

Hope that makes some sense.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
def largest_pyr(x):
    pyr=[sum([i**2 for i in range(1,k+1)]) for k in range(int(x**0.5)+1)]
    pyr=[i for i in pyr if i<=x]
    return pyr[-1]

>>>largest_pyr(15)
14
>>> largest_pyr(150)
140
>>> largest_pyr(1500)
1496
>>> largest_pyr(15000)
14910
>>> largest_pyr(150000)
149226
```